# Spring xml + JUnit - xml context file not working in src/test/resources but works in src/main/resources

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, junit

I'm having a problem with junit test like this. For some reason spring context files only work if I put them in the src/main/resources folder of the maven project. Intellij doesn't give me any warning but both junit test runner from mvn and from ide bomb.

Code and output in both cases included below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:/test-applicationContext.xml"})
public class DataSharingTest {

    AuthTokenService authTokenService;

    @Autowired
    public void setAuthTokenService(AuthTokenService authTokenService) {
        this.authTokenService = authTokenService;
    }

    @Test
    public void MyTest(){
        System.out.println(authTokenService);
    }
}
```

If the file is at src/test/resources/test-applicationContext.xml
I get

```
2014-07-29 16:44:18,061 main      ERROR TestContextManager    Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@69e328e0] to prepare test instance [com.jg.datasharing.DataSharingTest@4090c06f]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [test-applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [test-applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist. If I try a wildcard in the path it will stop complaining about file not found but will compalain that the bean is missing.
```

If I move the file to src/main/resources/test-applicationContext.xml it passes

```
2014-07-29 16:46:53,564 main      INFO  lBeanDefinitionReader Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [test-applicationContext.xml]
2014-07-29 16:46:53,778 main      INFO  ricApplicationContext Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@7426dbec: startup date [Tue Jul 29 16:46:53 EDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-07-29 16:46:53,904 main      INFO  ltListableBeanFactory Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@19202d69: defining beans [authTokenService,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
com.jg.security.token.auth.JwtAuthTokenService@1380cf2a
2014-07-29 16:46:53,995 Thread-1  INFO  ricApplicationContext Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@7426dbec: startup date [Tue Jul 29 16:46:53 EDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-07-29 16:46:53,996 Thread-1  INFO  ltListableBeanFactory Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@19202d69: defining beans [authTokenService,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why would the file not be found in the test context classpath??

Comment: have you tried putting it in an appropriate package, e.g. `classpath:com/mycompany/test-applicationContext.xml` ?

Comment: Same thing - the IDE sees the spring context but JUnit and Maven say the file isn't there:  IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [com/jg/datasharing/test-applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/jg/datasharing/test-applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: I tried both right beside the code (eg src/test/java/com/jg/datasharing) as well as in the resouces (src/test/resources/com/jg/datasharing). 
IDE refactored the path for me so it appears to be actual config related rather than (strictly) human error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the test/resources is added as classpath. You can verify in eclipse IDE as follows.

Right click on the project ->properties->java build path -> in Sources tab you should find {proejct}/src/test/resources (with option included all.)

If you cannot find the option you can manually add the directory or you can configure pom.xml as follows

```
<build>
   <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
   </testResources>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks so much - I'm just coming back to Java after a spending a good hunk of time working on scala. Really appreciate your help - I inherited this project with no test cases in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath*:test-applicationContext.xml")
```

Comment: I've tried that too - I get a bean not found exception if I use wildcards but the file not found error goes away. 

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.jg.security.token.auth.AuthTokenService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

Comment: It seems like it's somehow strictly related to the classpath in test not being visible to spring. If I throw it in the src/main classpath it's fine.

Comment: Is the file being copied over to target/test-classes when you run mvn clean test?